# My app in the google app engine won't deploy

Tags: google-app-engine

Whenever I try to deploy my app (a proxy) it returns this message:

```
C:\Python27\pythonw.exe: can't open file 'C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
2013-12-05 00:16:31 (Process exited with code 2)
```

I've checked it a thousand times and both the app in the engine and the title of the project on my app engine account page, have the same server name. I set the preferences correctly, yet the error is always that the file doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying the program `appcfg` which does the deployment doesnt exist.

Something about you SDK environment is wrong. Have a look and see if you can find appcfg.py in the patgh in the error message, and check where your SDK is currently installed.